# Is the sequence , 0,1/2,0,1/3,2/3,0,1/4,2/4,3/4,0..... equidistributed?

Tags: number-theory

Is the sequence ,

$$0,1/2,0,1/3,2/3,0,1/4,2/4,3/4,0..... $$
 equidistributed ?

A sequence $\{\xi_n\}$  is equidistributed in $[0,1),$ that is if 
$$\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\frac{Card\{1\leq n\leq N|\xi_n\in(a,b)\}}{N}=b-a$$

Well ,the sequence write in a formula is :
$$\xi_n=0,\;\; whenever\; n=k(k-1)/2+1$$
$$\xi_n=\frac{k}{m},\;\;whenever\;n=\frac{(m-1)(m–2)}{2}+k$$
$\forall N,(a,b)$,firt of all 0 is in the $(a,b)$, so 
$$Card\{k|\frac{k(k-1)}{2}+1\leq N\}=O(\sqrt{N})$$
Next we let 
$$\frac{(m-1)(m–2)}{2}+k\leq N$$
and
$$am\leq k\leq bm$$
Just like a nonlinear  arrangement problem, suppose the $m$ is the $x$-axis, the $k$ is the $y$-axis, the question now , is to estimate the integer  points of this area .

I don't know how to do next

Comment: Can you show us what progress you've made?

Comment: @norfair of course, I show it in the answer ..

Answer (score 1):

Well ,the sequence write in a formula is :
$$\xi_n=0,\;\; whenever\; n=k(k-1)/2+1$$
$$\xi_n=\frac{k}{m},\;\;whenever\;n=\frac{(m-1)(m–2)}{2}+k$$
$\forall N,(a,b)$,firt of all 0 is in the $(a,b)$, so 
$$Card\{k|\frac{k(k-1)}{2}+1\leq N\}=O(\sqrt{N})$$
Next we let 
$$\frac{(m-1)(m–2)}{2}+k\leq N$$
and
$$am\leq k\leq bm$$
Just like a nonlinear  arrangement problem, suppose the $m$ is the $x$-axis, the $k$ is the $y$-axis, the question now , is to estimate the integer  points of this area .